# Mac AD login with Centrify never completes, never times out

Tags: mac, active-directory, ldap

My work Mac has [Centrify](http://www.centrify.com/directcontrol/overview.asp) installed on it; it's part of the office's enormous Active Directory system, has IT policies applied to it automatically, I can connect to SMB network shares without re-authenticating, etc.  It seems to be working, except when I boot the machine and try to log in.

At the login screen, I can click the machine info a few times to see that "network accounts available" shows up with a nice green icon beside it. I enter my domain credentials, and a "wait" spinner shows up beside the password field.

The spinner stays there, effectively forever. I let it run for ~2-3 hours one day with no login, and no timeout.

If I boot with the network cable unplugged, I can log in no problem, presumably with cached AD credentials.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely sounds like a timeout problem, could be that the machine can't find a Domain Controller to respond to the login request. We have improved DirectControl to do a much better job of finding Domain Controllers and timing out in a reasonable time as well as simply falling back to on cached login when all else fails. Updates to the Centrify DirectControl are free and should resolve this issue. Just have your IT give us a call or email me directly.

Thanks
-David
david.mcneely@centrify.com